# AngularJS - Dependency Injection - test if module exists and if so add it

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Within my Angular App I want to inject two modules into my App through dependency injection. So:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngModule1', 'ngModule2']);

var module1 = angular.module('ngModule1', ['App']);
var module2 = angular.module('ngModule2', ['App']);
```

However what if module2 doesn't exist yet or is not properly instantiated. I want to do something like this:

```
 var App = angular.module('App', ['ngModule1']);

   //Test if module2 exists
    try {
        var temp = $injector.get('ngModule2');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Injector does not have Module 2!');
    }

 //Do something with temp to add it in App
```

The method above isn't valid but I want to know the proper way to add in a module after testing if it exists

Comment: `$injector.get` is not for getting a module, it is for getting a factory etc..registered in the loaded module. I think what you need is manual bootstrapping.

Comment: @PSL I never did inject modules before so that is why I said the above code isn't valid. I know how to inject services but not modules

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to test and add it.

```
var modules = ['existingModule', 'nonexistentModule'].filter(function (module) {
  try {
    return !!angular.module(module);    
  } catch (e) {}
});

angular.module('module', modules);
```

It is also possible to redefine module, but do it before you defined its components and bootstrapped it.

```
var app;

try {
    app = angular.module('app', ['existingModule', 'debatableModule']);
} catch (e) {
    app = angular.module('app', ['existingModule']);
}
```

But it may (and most probably does) indicate that something is wrong with app design.

`$injector` doesn't serve this purpose and it can't help to 'inject' a module into existing one.